# Superpositions of renewal processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

Consider a small number of independent **[renewal processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#Renewal_processes)**, with their events superposed to create a single point process from the union of their outputs. What techniques could I use to characterise the superposition? I would like to request **reading recommendations** for this.

The [Palm–Khintchine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm%E2%80%93Khintchine_theorem) tells us about a large number of renewal processes superposed, but that limit argument doesn't help for small numbers superimposed.

I expect Cox's 1967 book "Renewal Theory" covers this topic, but I can't see a list of contents for it. So before I go looking for it, and since it's fairly old, perhaps there are more recent textbooks that cover the subject well. Any recommendations please?

Comment: That text has a chapter dedicated to superposition of renewal processes, and can be found for cheap online. Also see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536488/when-superposition-of-two-renewal-processes-is-another-renewal-process